# Set Levels in MSOL

Tags: logic, type-theory

I'm trying to see how Martin Lof Type Theory can be encoded in Monadic Second Order Logic over trees or graphs. Specifically, how can set levels (cumulative hierarchy) a la Russel or a la Tarski be represented in MSOL over trees/graphs? Namely, set of sets should be contained in universe Set_2, while sets of sets of sets in Set_3 and so on.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to start with "simpler" things, such as how to encode types, contexts, and type families?

Comment: I was thinking of representing dependent types in a similar way to http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-354/p63.pdf and borrow general type theoretical developments from Ong&Kobayashi

Comment: Where in the reference you gave is there anything about representation of dependent types in MSOL? The paper seems to be about representation of ontological knowledge using dependent records.

Comment: i'm not aware of a work that represents deptypes in msol, but this p63.pdf does reduce deptypes into relations.